# got esprima error when use webpack with angular 1.5 + babel

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6, webpack

I use webpack with angular 1.5.x and got this error when I try to build with default devtool.

```
Error: Line 1365: Unexpected token )
at throwError (/Users/gnome/Documents/worldmed-app/node_modules/falafel/node_modules/esprima/esprima.js:1467:21)
at throwUnexpected (/Users/gnome/Documents/worldmed-app/node_modules/falafel/node_modules/esprima/esprima.js:1525:9)
at parsePrimaryExpression (/Users/gnome/Documents/worldmed-app/node_modules/falafel/node_modules/esprima/esprima.js:1833:16)
at /Users/gnome/Documents/worldmed-app/node_modules/falafel/node_modules/esprima/esprima.js:3588:38
at trackLeftHandSideExpressionAllowCall (/Users/gnome/Documents/worldmed-app/node_modules/falafel/node_modules/esprima/esprima.js:3492:61)
at parsePostfixExpression (/Users/gnome/Documents/worldmed-app/node_modules/falafel/node_modules/esprima/esprima.js:1939:20)
at /Users/gnome/Documents/worldmed-app/node_modules/falafel/node_modules/esprima/esprima.js:3588:38
at parseUnaryExpression (/Users/gnome/Documents/worldmed-app/node_modules/falafel/node_modules/esprima/esprima.js:2009:16)
at /Users/gnome/Documents/worldmed-app/node_modules/falafel/node_modules/esprima/esprima.js:3588:38
at parseBinaryExpression (/Users/gnome/Documents/worldmed-app/node_modules/falafel/node_modules/esprima/esprima.js:2097:16)
at /Users/gnome/Documents/worldmed-app/node_modules/falafel/node_modules/esprima/esprima.js:3588:38
at parseConditionalExpression (/Users/gnome/Documents/worldmed-app/node_modules/falafel/node_modules/esprima/esprima.js:2144:16)
at /Users/gnome/Documents/worldmed-app/node_modules/falafel/node_modules/esprima/esprima.js:3588:38
at parseAssignmentExpression (/Users/gnome/Documents/worldmed-app/node_modules/falafel/node_modules/esprima/esprima.js:2167:16)
at /Users/gnome/Documents/worldmed-app/node_modules/falafel/node_modules/esprima/esprima.js:3588:38
at parseExpression (/Users/gnome/Documents/worldmed-app/node_modules/falafel/node_modules/esprima/esprima.js:2191:20)
at /Users/gnome/Documents/worldmed-app/node_modules/falafel/node_modules/esprima/esprima.js:3588:38
at trackGroupExpression (/Users/gnome/Documents/worldmed-app/node_modules/falafel/node_modules/esprima/esprima.js:3451:16)
at parsePrimaryExpression (/Users/gnome/Documents/worldmed-app/node_modules/falafel/node_modules/esprima/esprima.js:1826:20)
at /Users/gnome/Documents/worldmed-app/node_modules/falafel/node_modules/esprima/esprima.js:3588:38
at trackLeftHandSideExpressionAllowCall (/Users/gnome/Documents/worldmed-app/node_modules/falafel/node_modules/esprima/esprima.js:3492:61)
at parsePostfixExpression (/Users/gnome/Documents/worldmed-app/node_modules/falafel/node_modules/esprima/esprima.js:1939:20)
at /Users/gnome/Documents/worldmed-app/node_modules/falafel/node_modules/esprima/esprima.js:3588:38
at parseUnaryExpression (/Users/gnome/Documents/worldmed-app/node_modules/falafel/node_modules/esprima/esprima.js:2009:16)
at /Users/gnome/Documents/worldmed-app/node_modules/falafel/node_modules/esprima/esprima.js:3588:38
at parseBinaryExpression (/Users/gnome/Documents/worldmed-app/node_modules/falafel/node_modules/esprima/esprima.js:2097:16)
at /Users/gnome/Documents/worldmed-app/node_modules/falafel/node_modules/esprima/esprima.js:3588:38
at parseConditionalExpression (/Users/gnome/Documents/worldmed-app/node_modules/falafel/node_modules/esprima/esprima.js:2144:16)
at /Users/gnome/Documents/worldmed-app/node_modules/falafel/node_modules/esprima/esprima.js:3588:38
at parseAssignmentExpression (/Users/gnome/Documents/worldmed-app/node_modules/falafel/node_modules/esprima/esprima.js:2167:16)
```

I have no clue where should I looking for unexpected token ')'.

And when I use `eval` dev tool, It's can build properly but it's error on safari

Please give me a suggestion where should I fix this mess. :(

Comment: did you find what was the issue with it?